# Clipped print output from CUPS / HPLJ5m

Tags: cups

When printing through the CUPS API, everything looks excellent when output to PDF and view the result in Firefox. But when printing to a real printer, HPLJ5m, the printing area gets clipped. I print on A4 paper and tries to configure that with options when creating the print job.
The height of the printed area corresponds to the size of US letter, coincidal or not? The position is nicely aligned. Without this masking everything would have been perfect. The print data is a PDF with just image data.
Maybe the option sent to cupsCreateDestJob() does not override all the rubbish in the .ppd-file for my printer? Can that, if necceccary, be done through the API?

```
  options=NULL; num_options=0;         
  num_options = D_cupsAddOption(CUPS_COPIES, "1", num_options, &options);
  num_options = D_cupsAddOption(CUPS_MEDIA, CUPS_MEDIA_A4, num_options, &options);
  num_options = D_cupsAddOption(CUPS_SIDES, CUPS_SIDES_ONE_SIDED, num_options, &options);

  info = D_cupsCopyDestInfo(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, printer);

  if (D_cupsCreateDestJob(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, printer, info,
                        &job_id, "tideq", num_options,
                        options) != IPP_STATUS_OK) goto failed;
```

Here is the relevant part of the print data sent to cups. There are margins for the dead zones at the borders.

```
%PDF-1.7
%åäö

1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages
     /Kids [3 0 R
            7 0 R
            ]
     /Count 2
     /MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  << /Type /Page
     /Parent 1 0 R
     /CropBox [0 0 595 842]
     /Resources 4 0 R
     /Contents 6 0 R
  >>
endobj

4 0 obj
  << /ProcSet [ /PDF /ImageB ]
     /XObject << /Im1 5 0 R >>
  >>
endobj

5 0 obj
  << /Type /XObject
     /Subtype /Image
     /Width 1281
     /Height 1500
     /ColorSpace /DeviceGray
     /BitsPerComponent 8
     /Length 3843001
     /Filter /ASCIIHexDecode
  >>
stream
<page data goes here>
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
  << /Length 40 >>
stream
  q
  555 0 0 802 20 20 cm
  /Im1 Do
  Q
endstream
endobj
```

Comment: When printing from LibreOffice the actual areas of the paper can be printed, so printer and driver can do it. Mousepad can do it. But the editor I has written myslf fails. It must be doable, but my ideas about what to try is exhausted. The CUPS API is so complex that I need a bit of help from someone more experienced with it. It's a program thought to be downloaded by others and just work, so I want to include everyting needed to and not rely on defaults that can be wrong.

Comment: "....does not override all the rubbish in the .ppd-file for my printer?"  The [PPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description) should contain the info (=definition) from your printer, and should not be overridden (and does not (or should not) contain rubbish)